# How do I use multiple GPUs with a saved and restored keras model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I am training to train and distribute my keras functional-model onto the different GPUs on my system. This works in the first step, after checking my GPU-utilization (command: watch -n0.5 nvidia-smi). After restoring the functional again, the parallelization for the different branches of the model does not work after all in the training.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Concatenate
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model, load_model, Sequential
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    Input_1=Input(shape=(256,),name="Input_1")
    Dense_1=Dense(128)(Input_1)
with tf.device('/gpu:1'):
    Input_2=Input(shape=(256,),name="Input_2")
    Dense_2=Dense(128)(Input_2)
with tf.device('/gpu:2'):
    Input_3=Input(shape=(256,),name="Input_3")
    Dense_3=Dense(128)(Input_3)
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    Concatenate_=Concatenate()([Dense_1,Dense_2,Dense_3])
    output=Dense(1)(Concatenate_)
model=Model(inputs=[Input_1,Input_2,Input_3],outputs=[output])
model=tf.keras.utils.multi_gpu_model(model,gpus=3)
model.compile(optimizer="sgd",loss="mean_squared_error")
model.save("./test.h5")
input_dict={}
for k in ["Input_1","Input_2","Input_3"]:
    input_dict.update({k: np.random.standard_normal((10000,256))})
    output_dict={model.layers[-1].name: np.random.standard_normal((10000,1))}
test_0=model.fit(x=input_dict,y=output_dict,batch_size=128,epochs=20)
del model

model=load_model("./test.h5")
test_1=model.fit(x=input_dict,y=output_dict,batch_size=128,epochs=20)
```

After restoration model in the last part of the code, the model uses only one GPU. Removing the line "model=tf.keras.utils.multi_gpu_model(model,gpus=3)" does not help after all.
My 3 GPUs are GEFORCE RTX 2080 Ti and I am using Anacondaa on Ubuntu. How do I make the model work with GPU-parallelization also when I restore it through "load_model"?

Comment: Is this, what you're looking for? `model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
model = tf.keras.utils.multi_gpu_model(model, gpus=num_gpus)
model.fit(..)`

Comment: @Sharky Unfortunately not. I have already tried out to use the "multi_gpu_model" method which is not effective. Maybe it might be that saving to a *.h5-file does not include the device assignment of the subnets?

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: @Sharky. No, there are no error messages.

Comment: Then what do you mean by saying multi_gpu_model is not effective? Have you checked GPU utilization rates?

Comment: I have checked GPU utilization. Seemingly, the "multi_gpu_model" method does not lead the whole process to utilize more than 1 GPU, according to GPU utilization. Actually, the lines with "*with tf.device('/gpu:0'):", etc.  lead to multiple GPUs working on the problem. There seems to be a difference between data parallelism and device parallelism. Device parallism works finely except when I load the model from a file. Data parallelism is not working at all.

Comment: multi_gpu_model uses concat layer as output. you need to use model.load_weights. You'll have to define model though

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193786/discussion-between-tintin-and-sharky).

Comment: parallelism works now as indicated by gpu-utilization. As pointed out I have to rebuild the architecture and use load_weights. The speed up through parallelism is not so big yet as hoped for, though.